Add folder in Maven build JAR
I am building a project with two external library. It requires 1 extra folder called models containing resources to run. This folder and two library jars must be put in root directory. When I build and run the project in IntelliJ IDEA, the app works smoothly. But when I build into JAR and run with java -jar, the library doesnot work properly. I check the file JAR and it doesnot contain folder models in it.
This is my external library:


<dependency>
   <groupId>jdf</groupId>
   <artifactId>jdf</artifactId>
   <version>1.0.0</version>
   <scope>system</scope>
   <systemPath>${project.basedir}/jdf.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>

<dependency>
   <groupId>vncorenlp</groupId>
   <artifactId>vncorenlp</artifactId>
   <version>1.2.0</version>
   <scope>system</scope>
   <systemPath>${project.basedir}/VnCoreNLP-1.2.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>



And my project structure:
 project
├─ models
├─ src
├─ jdf.jar
└─ VnCoreNLP-1.2.jar

I try to add it into build phase:


<build>
   <resources>
      <resource>
          <directory>models</directory>
      </resource>
   </resources>
</build>



But it always give me this error:

Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and
no embedded datasource could be configured.
Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource
[org/springframewo
rk/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]:
Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory
method 'dataSource' threw  exception with message: Failed to determine
a suitable driver class


Create a directory src/main/resources/models and put the required files there... also the idea to use system scope jar's is a bad idea... better install those file in your local repository ...

@khmarbaise I know that but the library requires to put folder there. I'd tried your suggestion before but the function did not work properly so I am finding another way :(((
